# Server to Server - secured connection from separate domains

Tags: windows-server

I have a box with 2019 Windows Datacenter in one domain, and I have Windows Datacenter 2019 in a completely different domain - I am looking for the best way to connect the two and keep the data secure. I would like to establish the connection so that they can file-share and access each other directories. This may be an elementary question, but I am looking for how best to set this up. Right now, I would think to use Windows Firewall with Advanced Security to create a endpoint to endpoint connection, but I still don't know what is needed to establish it as a secure connection.

Comment: Secure connection from what exactly? From whom are you trying to secure this connection? Currently your question is too unfocused.

Comment: I want to avoid the need to authenticate (if possible(via windows)), but also want the data to be transmitted without being in clear text format while the 2 servers are communicating/sharing data.

Comment: Which protocol will be used for the data transfer?

Comment: My attempts have been with TCP, because I was attempting to use Windows Firewall with Advanced Security to create a secure connection.

Comment: Will the data actually be transferred using TCP, or there is another application-layer protocol involved (e.g HTTP)?

Comment: So in wf.msc |
Connection Security Rules > New Rules |
Server to Server |
Endpoint 1 (My public IP) |
Endpoint 2 (Other public IP) |
Require authentication for inbound connections and request authentication for outbound connections |
Drop a IPsec certificate created from my PKI |
Select Domain and Private - Remove Public |
Name it, then enable it. | end.  

Currently this does not work, nor do I know if this is the best way to setup a connection that is secure - alternatively create a VPN? But that seems like more hassle?